# change the button text of datalist from out side the datalist

Tags: c#

I have a button named like and image control inside the datalist1 with updatepanel , which shows many records...and I want

for ex.

```
void Page_Load (sender s, Eventargs e)
if(check("select * from like where liked = 'liked'") == true)
{
    // then I want to change the text of the button to liked (in page_load)
}
```

check is a function which check the data is available or not.
    and I also want, when user click on this like button , the button text changed to liked 
    thanks for any help.

Comment: WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: We need more details